# Redirect login page when user already logged

Tags: php, redirect

I have a little problem with my script, and I need some help.

So the problem is: When the user is logged on, they can still open the login page again.

This is my script. **function.php**

```
function is_admin ($login, $password) 
{
    if ($login == ADMIN_LOGIN && $password == ADMIN_PASSWORD) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        setcookie('login', $login, $realtime+24*7, '/');
        setcookie('pass', md5($password), $realtime+24*7, '/');
        return false;
    }
}
$admin = is_admin($_COOKIE['login'], $_COOKIE['pass']);
```

This is **index.php**

```
if(!$admin && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/cp/login.php'){
    header('location: /cp/login');
}else
    header('location: /cp');
 }  
ob_start();
```

With this, all pages redirect to login, when user is not logged on, but when logged on, I can open the page `/cp/login`

I want a login page redirect to `/cp` when user is already logged in.

Where is the problem in this above?

Comment: Why are you storing the password in the cookie? Also `setcookie()` does **not** set the `$_COOKIE` variable. It's available automatically starting from the next request because cookies are send with requests.

Comment: @PeeHaa you mean in that is problem? Please give me ex.

Comment: I would be more than happy to give you my ex. But I am note sure she would agree.

Comment: hahaha i mean example

Comment: Please read the official docs of the functions you are using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

you need to start a session for the logged in user, and pass that about the pages, dont use a cookie.  That way you'll know if the user is logged in and if its appropriate for them to see certain content on the page.

at the top of each page put (before ANYTHING):

```
<?php
session_start();
```

then when youve successfully authenticated them, set a session variable.

```
// when authenticated
$_SESSION['username'] = $user->getUsername(); // or whatever you want
```

then on each page where you need to know if they're logged in:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) {
     // do something, render something, whatever.
}
```

to log them out

```
session_destroy();
```

#### security issues

- **dont** store anything security related in a cookie, thats suicide.
- **dont** use `PHP_SELF` in that form. [see here](https://phpsecurity.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/the-danger-of-php_self/)
- MD5 is a reversible hash, its not intended for encryption. Use `crypt()` instead.

#### useful info

- [sessions documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)